# How to embed a facebook like button in a HTML Newsletter?

Tags: html, facebook, email, facebook-like, newsletter

I would like my readers to like my fan page while reading my newsletter. How to embed the standard iFrame button count at the beginning of my email?

Comment: Online Marketing tools like Mailchimp or CampaignMonitor serve this standard: http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=180

Answer (score 1):

The standard iframe is imposible to use in email campaigns. But u can fake it a little bit by using the like/share image from Facebook and lik tot the share site.

```
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://domain.com'>
     <img src='http://domain.com/like.png' alt='Like my site' />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this link:

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://domain.com

Not a beautiful landing page though. It's probably better to link to your own page with the Like button as an IFRAME.

Answer (score -2):

So you want to know ‘How to add a ‘Facebook Like Button’ to your email template‘. Ever since MailChimp promised to add the functionality to their system we have seen a buzz with people wondering how they do it. This article is a quick and dirty guide to DIY Facebook Like Buttons embedded in email templates.  So no matter who your ESP is you can embed a Like Button within your email design.

Well to be perfectly honest it really is not that hard, however contrary to what you may have hoped it is not quite seamless and there is no way for it to be. It involves a 2 click process.

The simplest way and the one most likely to work for most users is to use the following code.

— The Code —

```
         <a href="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php? href=http://www.facebook.com/pages/Email-Expert/130177676994892?ref%3Dts&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80 target=">

         <img title="Facebook Like Button"   src="http://emailexpert.org/dontexist/likebutton.jpg" alt="" />
         </a>
```

—-ends—-

Instructions

1. Change the URL to the page you want ‘liked’
2. Change the img location and upload your likebutton image.